# Launchpad fails to build a package for my PPA

Tags: ppa, compiling, launchpad

I'm trying to build a package on Launchpad's Debian build system for PPAs but I'm having some issues with a certain package.

The package I'm trying to build (zorin-xwinwrap) contains a source C file which I'm trying to get to compile and build on Launchpad's server so that it would install and work on 32 bit (i386) and 64 bit (amd64) systems. Unfortunately I keep on getting an

> Error code 2

With the `debian/rules` file and I have no clue how to fix this issue.

The following link is the source package of the software I'm trying to add to my PPA: http://ubuntuone.com/4i8XCtqen2AdpB20oulgrI

The following link is the buildlog for the failed package on Launchpad: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/107687586/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.zorin-xwinwrap_1.0.2_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Comment: Try `#debian-mentors` on irc.debian.org...

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing link dependencies.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags#A-Wl.2C--as-needed

Try setting linker flag --no-as-needed for your compilation. How to achieve this, is left as an exercise to the reader